# Qt how to put QLabel without any layout

Tags: qt, layout, qlabel

Can someone tell me, is it possible to use `QWidget` without any Layout. I have `QSplashScreen` with image as a background and I want to add one more `QLabel` with another image inside of my splash screen, but because splash screen is not resizable and there is no reason to do this, I haven't want use any `Layout`. I want just add `QLabel` with image and set its geometry.

Comment: the best way to handle splash screens is to override `drawContents` and draw your other image there using the painter. Messing around with widgets on splash screens is more hassle than it's worth.

Comment: Another idea you can try is: don't use a QLabel to store the the background image, but use stylesheets: setStyleSheet("background-image: :/bkgImg.png"); and then you can use layouts to show stuff over the background.

Comment: @Zlatomir for background I'm using `setPixmap()`, QLabel is only example, on that splash screen I need to add two extra controls (one for text and one for logo).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's nothing to it: just add your widget as a child of the splash screen, and manually set its position, and perhaps size as well.

```
int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
  QApplication a{argc, argv};
  QSplashScreen splash;
  QLabel image{&splash};
  image.move(50, 50);
  ...
  splash.show();
  return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: just out of curiosity - why `{}` instead of `()`?

Comment: @ramtheconqueror It's shinier, just look at the glints on those inflection points :) But seriously, because it's a unified way to initialize things in modern C++.

Comment: Ok, this is work well, but how to do this in constructor. I tried use `QLabel image{this}` instead of `QLabel image{&splash}` but it's not works.
Here is my code:
[link](http://pastebin.com/TBKcffYg)

Comment: @MichałKaczorowski Works for me. What compiler do you use?

Comment: Ok, I solved my problem. I tried create class without declared field -.- When I moved QLabel image{this} to definition of class in *.hpp file and remove this in constructor all works fine.

Answer (score 2):

Much the same as Kuba Ober's above code with some minor but necessary additions.

```
QPixmap pixmap(":/splash.png");   //from resources
QSplashScreen splash(pixmap);

QLabel label(&splash);
label.setPixmap(pixmap);    //you can use different image for label
label.setScaledContents(true);
label.setGeometry(50,50,50,50);
splash.show();
```